# How to Hide tableview height when click on button in Swift

Tags: swift, tableview, height, show-hide

With the below code I am able to get tableview dynamic height but when i hide the tableview still the dynamic height is remaining in the view why?

*I am taking tableview height `0` in storyboard*

**Code:** Initially i am hiding the tableview, here `workExpBtn` will be like expand / collepse button. so first time if i click workExpBtn then tableview is showing but if i click the button 2nd time then tableview is hiding but its height remains in view why?

**if i hide the tableview then i need to make tableview height as `0` again, but how?**

```
class WorkVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var workExpTablHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var workExpTableview: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    workExpTablHeight.constant = 0
    workExpTableview.isHidden = true
}


@IBAction func workExpBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    
    workExpTableview.isHidden = workExpTableview.isHidden ? false : true
    workExpTableview.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)
    workExpTableview.reloadData()
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    let tableview = object as? UITableView
    if tableview == self.workExpTableview{
        if(keyPath == "contentSize"){
            if let newvalue = change?[.newKey]
            {
                let newsize  = newvalue as! CGSize
                workExpTablHeight.constant = newsize.height
            }
        }
    }
}
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return 10
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WorkExpCell", for: indexPath) as! WorkExpCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
}
```

**initially tableview hiding o/p:**

[image]

**when i click on button tableview is showing o/p with green cells:**

[image]

**when i click again on button tableview is hiding but height remains o/p:**

[image]

Comment: put both table view and label view in the vertical stack that hides tableView it will works

Answer (score 1):

Use section as tap-able header and options as rows, when you have to show options then return rows equal to your options and when you have to hide option return *0* in *numberOfRowInSection* method.